# PostgreSQL: Compare and change values in the same column based on conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case

I have data in the form:

```
Name   Category  my_value
Ana    A         42
Ana    B         33
Bob    A         33
Bob    B         33
Carla  A         42
Carla  B         33
```

I would like the following to happen for the same **Name**:

- when A and B share the same value, A has no value associated to it (in col my_alue).
- when A an B are different, A keeps its value and B has no value associated to it (in col my_value).

I've attempted:

```
select *,
    case when Category = 'A' and Category = 'B' 
        then my_value = null
        else my_value
        end as "Value A (corrected)"
from my_table
```

Obviously wrong... not sure how I can also implement the condition to set B as null if the values are different. And how to implement a group by here to compare the categories for the same name...

Ideally, This is the output I'm after *(changes in the same column as I have more categories for each name in it, i.e. C, D, E... - only need changes in A and B)*

```
Name   Category  Value
Ana    A         42                      
Ana    B                                 
Bob    A                                 
Bob    B         33                                       
Carla  A         42    
Carla  B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to itself where the other row is the A/B compliment:

```
select
  t1.Name,
  t1.Category,
  case
    when t1.my_value = t2.my_value and t1.Category = 'A' then null
    when t1.my_value != t2.my_value and t1.Category = 'B' then null
    else t1.my_value
  end as my_value
from my_table t1
left join my_table t2 on t2.Name = t1.Name
  and t2.Category != t1.Category
  and t2.Category in ('A', 'B')
  and t1.Category in ('A', 'B')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/43cf3/2).

A join is made to t2 if t1’s Category is 'A' and t2’s is 'B' or visa versa and the Name is the same.

Comment: What keywords am I after to learn more about the t1 and t2 approach you've followed?

Comment: @Joehat the terms`t1` and `t2` are *aliases*. `left join` is an *outer join* (one that succeeds even if there is no matching row in the other table). This is an example of a *self join* (the table is joined to itself).